# get unique records existing only once per day in a date range

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a case where I want to extract the device ids (DIDs) that exist only and only once for each day in a certain period. I have tried different methods and partitions but I seem to only be able to get that data individually per day (where date = X, but I need a query where I can put where date between X & Y)

Example, this is the data:

```
DID date     
A   2019-01-01
A   2019-01-01
A   2019-01-02
A   2019-01-03
B   2019-01-01
B   2019-01-02
B   2019-01-03
C   2019-01-01
C   2019-01-02
C   2019-01-02
C   2019-01-03
D   2019-01-01
D   2019-01-02
D   2019-01-03
```

The query should return only B & D(because B & D exists once in each day from 01 to 03)
I also wish to get the count, which would be 2 in this case

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the devices to exist only **once** on **each** day of the period, so if you `group by did` you need to return the `did`s that have `count(date)` and `count(distinct date)` equal to the number of days of that period:

```
select did
from tablename
where date between cast('2019-01-01' as date) and cast('2019-01-03' as date)
group by did
having 
  count(distinct date) = cast('2019-01-03' as date) - cast('2019-01-01' as date) + 1
  and
  count(date) = cast('2019-01-03' as date) - cast('2019-01-01' as date) + 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ku2sNcasVViifULoNKq7bT/4).
Or:

```
select t.did
from (
  select did, date
  from tablename
  where date between cast('2019-01-01' as date) and cast('2019-01-03' as date)
  group by did, date
  having count(*) = 1
)t  
group by t.did
having count(*) = cast('2019-01-03' as date) - cast('2019-01-01' as date) + 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ku2sNcasVViifULoNKq7bT/5).
Result:

```
| did |
| --- |
| B   |
| D   |
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to aggregate by `DID` and assert that the total count is equal to the count of distinct dates.  If this assertion passes, it means that a given `DID` has only distinct dates present.

```
SELECT DID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DID
HAVING COUNT(date) = COUNT(DISTINCT date);
```

### Demo

If you want to get the total count of matching `DID`, then you could subquery the above and take `COUNT(*)`.  Or, if you wanted to use the same query you might try:

```
SELECT DID, COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DID
HAVING COUNT(date) = COUNT(DISTINCT date);
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a false positive if a DID had no entries on one day and two on the following day?

Comment: Did the OP give any indication that this might be a possibility?

Comment: i like the simplicty of this one but has chance of false positives